# How to read the filter settings from an Excel table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

strong textI have a table in Excel where I need to read the filter settings.
I just don't get the syntax right.
E.g. in Column 5 I have filtered for 4 strings, and `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_Input").AutoFilter.Filters(5).Count` works and gives me 4.

Now I need to get these 4 strings.
`Criteria1` seems to be an array with 4 entries.
`LBound(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_Input").AutoFilter.Filters(5).Criteria1)` gives 1.
`UBound(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_Input").AutoFilter.Filters(5).Criteria1)` gives 4.

But `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_Input").AutoFilter.Filters(5).Criteria1(1)` doesn't work and I tried many other syntaxes which all don't work.

In the locals window I do see the entries - just cannot grab them.

[image]

**This is not a duplicate to the other post** - although it gives the same error message. the other post does not solve it - and the suggestion to change the class module cannot help when I ask to get at Excel's functionality.

But `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_Input").AutoFilter.Filters(5).Criteria1()(1)` is an answer (just in case it helps somebody who spends hours with this)

Comment: `doesn't work` - what does it do instead?

Comment: It gives an error message. Property let procedure not defined

Comment: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_Input").AutoFilter.Filters(5).Criteria1()(1)`.

Comment: I don't think that the other post answers this as it refers to user built class modules while my question refers to the excel built in functionality (where I cannot add something to the class).
But the answer is 
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_Input").AutoFilter.Filters(5).Criteria1()(1)